# Parsing EDI X12 835 XML into a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, edi, x12

I have been trying to parse 835 XML in to a table. I am using the following code

```
Declare @XML XML

SET @XML = (SELECT *
            FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\835\XML\Processremitcombined.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS data)

 Declare @NoClaims Int

INSERT INTO tblX12835_Copy(BPR_Payment, BPR_EffectiveEntryDate , TRn_TraceNumber, N1_HospiceNPI ,NM1_Patientlastname, NM1_PatientFirstName, NM1_HIC, DTM_claimDate)
    SELECT
        -- X.product.query('National_Provider_Identifier').value('.', 'INT'),
        X.Product.query('Loop/Loop/CLP/CLP04').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')' ',
        X.Product.query('BPR/BPR16').value('.', 'datetime'),
        X.Product.query('TRN/TRN02').value('.', 'nvarchar(25)'),
        X.product.query('Loop/N1/N104').value('.', 'nvarchar(25)'),
        X.product.query('Loop/Loop/NM1/NM103').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
        X.product.query('Loop/Loop/NM1/NM104').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')' ',
        X.product.query('Loop/Loop/NM1/NM109').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')' ',
        X.product.query('Loop/Loop/DTM/DTM02').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')' '
    FROM 
        @XML.nodes('/Interchange/Interchange/FunctionGroup/Transaction') AS X(Product)
```

The only problem is that there are  multiple nested loops containing multiple Patient information for the same health facility. So when my routine pulls that data and inserts it into a table columns like patientFirstname contains all the name in that loop. I want to iterate through these loops and pull each patients information as a separate record.

Comment: This is why translation software exists.  You could take the 835 and dump it directly to SQL.  Now, you're parsing it to XML and then converting to SQL and have little flexibility.  Multiple points of failure, and lots to maintain.   To keep your paradigm, you'd probably have to go back and create an XML node for each iteration so that it creates the record on the SQL side.